# Is there a way to delete all Yahoo mail at once?

Tags: yahoo-mail

Yahoo mail allows you to scroll down to load more emails in batches of 50-100, but with thousands of emails, this becomes very time consuming.

Is there a way to select all email in the inbox at once and delete them all in one quick operation?

Comment: Can you not click the "Select All" checkbox in the upper left?

Answer (score 2):

As variant, you can use some IMAP client, like Thunderbird, and move all messages from inbox to trash folder.

You can get the [IMAP Server settings from Yahoo help](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mobile/imapnbspsettings-yahoo-mail-sln4075.html).